# Sequentially iterate over arbitrary number of vectors in C++

Tags: c++, loops, vector, iterator, chaining

I have a function that gathers and concatenates some number of vectors (with the same types of elements, of course). Here is the bare-bones idea of it:

```
vector<A> combined;
...
for(int i = 0; i < someNumber; i++)
    combined.insert(combined.end(), GetNextRange().begin(), GetNextRange().end());
```

All of this is done so that I can sequentially iterate over the combined set. I would like to achieve this without all of the copying business.

Since GetNextRange() actually returns a reference to the next vector in line, how can I make use of that fact and put the references together/line them up for the desired access method?

Answer (score 5):

First off, if `GetNextRange()` actually, indeed does return the next vector, your use of `GetNextRange()` twice to get the `begin()` and the `end()` won't do you much good. At the very least you'd need to do something along the lines of

```
for (int i = 0; i != someNumber; ++i) {
    std::vector<A> const& tmp(GetNextRange());
    combined.insert(combined.end(), tmp.begin(), tmp.end());
}
```

If you want to make this somewhat nice you can create a custom iterator which internally stores the current vector, the index, and a current position. It will probably be an input iterator actually storing the current information in a suitable shared record so it can be copied.

Here is a simple (and untested) implementation:

```
class joined_iterator {
    struct record {
        record(int limit)
            : index(0)
            , limit(limit)
            , current(limit? &GetNextRange(): 0)
            , pos()
        {
            if (this->current) {
                this->current->begin();
            }
        }
        int                            index;
        int                            limit;
        std::vector<A> const*          current;
        std::vector<A>::const_iterator pos;
    };
    std::shared_ptr<record> ptr;
public:
    joined_iterator(int limit): ptr(std::make_shared<record>(limit)) {}
    bool operator== (joined_iterator const& other) const {
        return this->ptr->current
            ? bool(other.ptr->current)
            : !bool(other.ptr->current);
    }
    bool operator!= (joined_iterator const& other) const {
        return !(*this == other);
    }
    A const& operator*() const { return *this->ptr->pos; }
    A const* operator->() const { return &*this->ptr->pos; }
    joined_iterator& operator++() {
        if (++this->ptr->pos == this->ptr->current->end()) {
            if (++this->ptr->index == this->ptr->limit) {
                this->ptr->current = 0;
            }
            else {
                this->ptr->current = &GetNextRange();
                this->ptr->pos = this->ptr->current->begin();
            }
        }
        return *this;
    }
    joined_iterator operator++(int) {
        joined_iterator rc(*this);
        this->operator++();
        return rc;
    }
};
```

Comment: I was going to answer something along this lines. An iterator adaptor holding a `vector<vector<A>*>`, and `vector<vector<A>*>::[const_]iterator` to refer to the current vector, and an `vector<A>::iterator` to refer to the current object in that vector. Not sure why you want it to be an input iterator with shared state though?

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas (IB really needs name completion): I'm not storing a `std::vector<std::vector<A>*>`. Doing so would, indeed, provide a relatively simple way to create a forward iterator and, with a bit of extra work, also a bidirectional iterator. The above input iterator is the immediate idea but it can be turned into use a different layout quite easily.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to iterate over two vectors sequentially and thought there has to be a more simple answer. My following solution (C++11 implementation, but easily adapted to older versions) - hinted at in the comments on Dietmar Kühls answer which I initially overlooked as they are quite burried - is not as sophisticated but did the trick for my use case:

```
vector<vector<A>*> v_ps;
for ( int i = 0; i != someNumber; ++i ) {
    v_ps.push_back( &GetNextRange() );
}
for( auto v_p : v_ps ){
    for( A& el : *v_p ){
        // do what you wish with el
    }
}
```

Note: I assume `GetNextRange()` returns the next vector to be iterated over

Note II: As it is not as sophisticated, it has drawbacks especially requiring a double for-loop all the time. It is upon you and your application if that is acceptable.

Note III: I leave the possibility for changes on the individual elements intentially open